# Is it possible to know on google maps the names of all the locations in all the directions for a finite distance?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, cartography

I am working on a hyper local courier delivery application.

I would like to know the names of all the city blocks or municipal wards which fall within a finite radius, fixing the user's position as the center of the circle.

I tried the traveling sales methods or sectors method. However Google restricts the multiple location search to 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Overpass-Turbo which queries OSM data. You can set the bounds and OSM tags you want to search.

https://overpass-turbo.eu/